# How to find the postion of this point (canvas)?

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas

http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/9305/fffnv.png

Do i need to solve a math, is there a easy way to solve this problem?

Comment: Well, you never NEED to do mathematics to solve a mathematical problem. You might try divine inspiration. Or, try putting the plot under your pillow at night, and hope the tooth fairy will leave an answer. But in the end, mathematics will be the most consistent solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you do need some math to get this going.

`Math.atan ((y-y')/(x-x'))` will get you the angle (in Radians) of the first line from the horrizon.

Add Pi/2 (90 degrees) to this angle to get the angle of the z line.

You can then use `Math.sin`  and `Math.cos` `multiplied by z to find the coordinates of the third point.

Comment: This is wrong. To get the angle you need to use `atan` (not `tan`) or even better than `atan(y/x)` is `atan2(y, x)` that handles the full circle and doesn't need all cases for different quadrants. Also to find the resulting point you need to use `cos` and `sin` (not `acos` and `asin`).

Comment: Removed downvote. Still I think that using `atan` instead of `atan2` is a bad idea because you've problems when `dx==0` and because you have to handle all cases for positive/negative `dx` or `dy` (when computing `dy/dx` two negatives or two positives will give you the same result thus dropping the sign information, while clearly the angle is the opposite direction in the two cases; (+1,+1) = PI/4, (-1,-1) = -3/4 PI).

Answer (score 2):

First you compute the angle of the line from second to first point

```
var angle = Math.atan2(first.y - second.y, first.x - second.x);
```

then you compute the resulting point using `sin` and `cos`

```
var result = {x : second.x + z*Math.cos(angle + Math.PI/2),
              y : second.y + z*Math.sin(angle + Math.PI/2)};
```